# Django - URL template tag breaks with subdomains

Tags: django-templates, subdomain, django-1.5

I use a custom middleware for mapping subdomains to applications' `urls.py` by assigning the relevant `urls.py` to the `request.urlconf` variable.

This works fine, with the exception of the `{% url %}` template tag.
I'm getting a `NoReverseMatch` and can't figure out why.
The debug page shows that the `reverse` function receives a value in the `view_name` parameter, so it should work.

This happens to *every* `{% url %}` tag in the template.
If I switch to folder-like urls (eg `myproject.com/sub`, instead of `sub.myproject.com`), the tags work fine.

Any ideas on why this happens and how can this be fixed are much appreciated.

Comment: You might want to look into https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts - havent done it.. just a thought

Comment: @karthikr, thanks. I read through this page, but nothing there to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after not finding what I needed, I came to the following solution.
I discarded the `request.urlconf` mapping and went for rewriting `request.path_info`.
I'm posting my solution here, in case someone runs into this problem.

First step, add the following middleware to your project:

```
class SubdomainMiddleware:
    """Subdomain for Django"""
    def process_request(self, request):
        domain_parts = request.get_host().lower().replace('www.', '').split('.example.com', 1)
        if len(domain_parts) > 1 and domain_parts[0]:
            subdomain = domain_parts[0]
        else:
            subdomain = None

        if subdomain:
            if request.path_info[-1] != '/':
                request.path_info += '/'
            request.path_info = '/%s%s' % (subdomain, request.path_info)
```

Next, add the following code that overrides the `reverse` function:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core import urlresolvers

_reverse = urlresolvers.reverse

def reverse(*args, **kwargs):
    # In case reversing a full url
    if args[0].startswith('http'):
        return args[0]
    # In case reversing a url name
    if '/' not in args[0]:
        url = _reverse(*args, **kwargs)
    else:
        # In case reversing a url path
        url = args[0]

    parts = url.strip('/').split('/', 1)
    subdomain = parts[0]
    path = parts[1] if len(parts) > 1 else ''
    protocol = 'http://' if settings.DEBUG else 'https://'
    return '%s%s%s/%s' % (protocol, subdomain, '.example.com', path)

urlresolvers.reverse = reverse
```

I placed it in the same file the custom middleware sits.

**That's it!**

As far as I know and tested, everything works: reversing, redirecting, template {% url %} tags etc.

Note:
I made three assumptions in this code:

- The domain name is `example.com`. Change it as you need, place it in `settings.py`, whatever suits you.
- The subdomain maps to a subfolder. E.g. `sub.example.com` will be converted to `example.com/sub`.
- My site uses SSL anywhere. So I simply check for `settings.DEBUG` value in the custom `reverse` function to see if it should use `http` or `https`.

Hope it helps.